# Pandas.replace not removing character from data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with the character `"` in some places (Python 2.7).
I want to remove all of the `"` from the data. I'm using the following method:

```
data_frame.replace(to_replace'"', value = '')
```

However, the data frame stays the same and the action doesn't take place.
Any advice on what the problem is would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemID': {0: 8988, 1: 8988, 2: 6547, 3: 6547}, 
                   'Description': {0: 'Tall Chair', 1: 'Tall Chair', 2: 'Big" Pillow', 3: 'Big Pillow'}, 
                   'Feedback': {0: 'I hated it""', 1: 'Best chair" ever', 2: 'Soft and amazing', 3: 'Horrific color'}})
print df
   Description          Feedback  ItemID
0   Tall Chair      I hated it""    8988
1   Tall Chair  Best chair" ever    8988
2  Big" Pillow  Soft and amazing    6547
3   Big Pillow    Horrific color    6547

print df.replace({'"': ''}, regex=True)
  Description          Feedback  ItemID
0  Tall Chair        I hated it    8988
1  Tall Chair   Best chair ever    8988
2  Big Pillow  Soft and amazing    6547
3  Big Pillow    Horrific color    6547
```

Comment: ah, nice, works better on a DataFrame than my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer is perfect for replacing in one column.

Comment: Thanks! df = df.replace({'"': ''}, regex=True) works great!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method `str.replace` of `Series`

So:

```
data_frame.foo.str.replace(to_replace'"', value = '')
```

`foo` being the name of a column

```
> df
    foo
0  "bar"

> df.foo.str.replace('"', '')
0    bar
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

If you have many columns, but then @jezrael answer is better I guess:

```
for s in df:
    if df[s].dtype == "object": # to avoid converting non-string column into string
        df.loc[:,s] = df.loc[:,s].str.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score -1):

Either set the `inplace` flag to `True` or reassign the output back to `data_frame`:

```
data_frame.replace(to_replace'"', value = '', inplace=True)
```

or

```
data_frame = data_frame.replace(to_replace'"', value = '')
```

Answer (score -1):

The `replace` function returns a new DataFrame with the replaced data.   Try:

```
data_frame = data_frame.replace(to_replace='"', value='')
```